# Sending Meeting invite in lightning

Tags: event, lightning-events

i have worked in Salesforce Classic for sending meeting invite thru EVENT calendar. But in lightning, I can only save meeting invite. how can i send same meeting invite to contacts on email in lightning. And also store  when they are accepting or rejecting the invite.

Answer (score 2):

Add the attendees field to your event layout.
All people intended to receive an invitation should be added as attendees
You can review this article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_events_lex.htm&type=5
Section: Event Attendees
Lightning Experience offers event attendees, which are similar to event invitees in Salesforce Classic, with a few differences.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify - when you add Contacts as Attendees they do NOT receive event invitations. Internal Users added as Attendees do receive event invitations.
Vote for my idea to get this into LEX - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Ca5EQAS